# Zoomcharts - Using Geochart as a parentChart for netchart

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts

We're trying out Zoomcharts' Geocharts to plot nodes.

It turns out that there are nodes with coordinates (A) and nodes (B) that are connected to (A) but don't have coordinates of their (B's) own.

At first we'd tried using OpenLayers (without geochart) and placing Zoomcharts' netchart on the coordinate, but the central node (A) cannot be made static in the basic netchart API.

So we're looking to use free floating nodes (B) around static nodes (A) by either injecting netchart into geochart or finding an setting that allows geochart to use nodes that don't have coordinates.

Is this possible, or do I have to resort to calculating force every time a user drags a node?

edit: the question has bee moved to the zoomcharts forums.

Answer (score 0):

Additional details here: https://forum.zoomcharts.com/t/freefloating-nodes-on-geochart/1299/14

Looking at this question again, NetChart supports locked nodes with floating nodes. what you could do is translate the fixed locations to x/y space of the NetChart and plot that on top of your map. This way you could have map and floating nodes. Note, that if you want to map/zoom map, you should sync the coordinates of the fixed nodes in the overlay NetChart object.

Comment: Haha, if you look at the username, I was the one who asked that on the zoomcharts forums. Didn't get exactly what I wanted, but the project finished with a couple workarounds.